# generic timeout for apex:actionFunction

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, actionfunction

What I'm trying to do is to call function from apex controller on mu VF page with timeout.
For this purpose I've decided to add next code
 `<apex:actionFunction name="searchAuthProducts" action="{!searchAuthorizedProducts}" reRender="none" onComplete="rerenderResults()"/>`

also I have js script -

```
 <script>
var timer;
    function searchWithTimeout(){
        this.timer = setTimeout(searchAuthProducts(), 10000);

    }

    function resetTimer(){           
        clearTimeout(this.timer);        
    }
```

And VF field that invoke js method -

```
<apex:inputText value="{!productName}" styleClass="slds-input" onKeyUp="searchWithTimeout();" onKeyDown="resetTimer();"/>
```

But it doesn't work, function fired right after *OnKeyUp*.
Do you have any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by adding the parentheses, you're actually calling the function. Instead, you want to pass in the function itself as a reference. To do this, pass in just the function's name without the parentheses.

```
// Will be called after 10 seconds if not cancelled
this.timer = setTimeout(searchAuthProducts, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this.

Here is my solution 
vf input:

```
 <apex:inputText value="{!productName}" styleClass="slds-input" onKeyDown="searchWithTimeout();"/>
```

js code:

```
<script>
var timer;

function searchWithTimeout(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(()=>{searchAuthProducts()}, 1200);
    }
</script>
```